# Removing Timestamp from Pandas Column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with the following DataFrame column containing `Date |TimeStamp | Name | Message` as a string

```
59770        [08/10/18, 5:57:43 PM] Luke: Message
59771   [08/10/18, 5:57:48 PM] Luke: Message
59772     [08/10/18, 5:57:50 PM] Luke: Message
```

I'm trying to remove the timestamp from the column and my expected output is:

```
59770   Luke: Message
59771   Luke: Message
59772   Luke: Message
```

I tried using

```
import re
df.iloc[:,0] = list(map(lambda x : re.sub(".*\d:\d\d\s[a|p]m","", x)[12:],df.iloc[:,0]))
```

But since the length of each string is different this method makes makes it worse.

Please Advise.

Comment: Do the timestamps always end with `] `? Can't you just do `df.iloc[:,0].apply(lambda x: x.split("] ")[1])`?

Comment: Yeah, all time stamps end with `] ` your method does remove the time stamp but results in `[Luke: Message]` instead of `Luke: Message`

Comment: I'm not following here - do you have three columns or is there no proper delimiter in your csv? you could simply do `df.drop('timestamp',1)` ?

Comment: @Manakin The column contains `'5:57:43 PM] Luke: Message'` as a string and yes there is no proper delimiter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the extract string function. A couple of options depending on quite how you want to have the results.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['5:57:43 PM] Luke: Message',
                           '5:57:48 PM] Luke: Message',
                           '5:57:50 PM] Luke: Message']})
```

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

df['text'].str.extract(r'\s*(.{10})](.*)')
```

```
            0               1
0  5:57:43 PM   Luke: Message
1  5:57:48 PM   Luke: Message
2  5:57:50 PM   Luke: Message
```

Or if you want the name and messages separate:

```
df['text'].str.extract(r'\s*(.{10})](.*):(.*)')
```

```
            0      1         2
0  5:57:43 PM   Luke   Message
1  5:57:48 PM   Luke   Message
2  5:57:50 PM   Luke   Message
```

Comment: Thanks! The second approach worked like a charm!

Comment: Please take a look at the updated question, How do I split it into 4 columns `Date |TimeStamp | Name | Message`